# New Apple TV screensavers not downloading

Tags: appletv

I've read about and seen other people have new cities appear in the Aerial Apple TV screensaver. My Apple TV, and with the latest software, doesn't seem to ever show these. Has anyone else had this? I've also experienced a black screen when the screeensaver is meant to otherwise appear.

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this? Still appears to be an issue.

Comment: @joshfarrant I ended up restoring my Apple TV. This isn't as destructive as it sounds, since most things restore automatically when you sign in.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to change how often Apple TV downloads new vidoes from Never to Daily, Weekly, or Monthly. Open settings > general > screensaver > download new videos

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually always had that setting set to Daily.